# How to turn off "applying profile" and "profile applied" notifications in Tasker

Tags: tasker, profiles

Whenever a new profile is applied there is a small gray round popup at the bottom of the screen that reads "Applying profile: {profile name}" and then "profile applied"

I want to stop these notifications.

Comment: I found the culprit. It's an app called Kernel Tuner. The notifications are called "toast notifications" It looks like a program bug that even though i turn toast notifications off, when I reopen the app, they are ticked back on again and cannot be unchecked.

Comment: Furthermore , even though the app has a bug in kitkat and continued to display those annoying toast notifications,  i was able to disable all notifications from the app by going into system settings -> apps and finding the app and unchecking notifications. Problem solved.